# How to translate "to pledge"?

Tags: word-meaning

How to translate "You have successfully pledged €149.00 to Amikumu" ?

Could it be "sincere promesi"?

Comment: Bonvenon al Stack Exchange, Yves! Mi gxojas vidi vin cxi tie! :-D Kaj ege bona demando.

Comment: Simpla "promesi" pli ol sufiĉas.

Answer (score 12):

Considering I've been running the [Amikumu campaign](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1770123604/amikumu-the-app-to-use-languages-with-people-near) all day, this word has been bothering me too. Then finally when I was writing up the FAQ for the question of how to get a member reward and a sponsor reward at the same time, I just naturally without hesitation translated this in my head as *promespagi* and it just worked, so I personally believe this is the best possible translation.

Comment: Very nice! I guess that depending on how you look at it (or even depending on how the specific crowdfunding site works), _pagpromesi_ could be a good alternative too.

Comment: I also thought about *pagpromesi*, but for some reason the alterative sounded (and still sounds) more correct in my head. / Mi ankaŭ pensis pri *pagpromesi*, sed ial la alternativo sonis (kaj daŭre sonas) pli ĝusta en mia kapo.

Comment: If a "pledge" is a form of promise to pay (in the future) the form in Esperanto has to be "pagpromesi".  "Promespagi" would be making the actual payment, fulfilling the pledge.

Comment: @Lee, I'm glad we agree then! Pledging is making the actual payment. It just only gets fully processed at the end of the campaign.

Answer (score 10):

A few years back, I created the [Esperanto version the website PledgeBank.com](http://www.liberafolio.org/2006/blairpromesas) (now sadly defunct). We just went with *promesi* then. The Esperanto site was called PromesoBanko.com and each "pledge" was just a "promeso".

The scope of PledgeBank was broader than KickStarter, in that people weren't necessarily pledging money for a project, but could be pledging to do something specific, to go somewhere, or just to publicly declare their support for something. As such, *promespagi* wouldn't have been appropriate for that. Even in the context of KickStarter, I'm not sure that there's much wrong with simply *promesi*.

Answer (score 8):

Ĝusta traduko estus ekzemple:

- *Vi sukcese promesis 149 eŭrojn al Amikumu.*

La proponita kunmetaĵo "promespagi" estas ege stranga. Oni povas nur mire skui la kapon klopodante deĉifri ian eventualan signifon.

Se oni nepre volas havi la vorton *pagi* en la esprimo, ĝi estu ekzemple *promesis pagi* anstataŭ la simpla *promesis*. Tio tamen estas neniel bezonata, ĉar estas jam klare dirite, ke la promeso temas pri monsumo (*promesis 149 eŭrojn*) kaj do ne povas esti io alia ol promeso pagi.

Answer (score 7):

For single word translation, you might look at existing services like [lernu](http://lernu.net/eo/vortaro), [revo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) kaj [tatoeba](http://tatoeba.org/epo/sentences/search?query=pledge&from=und&to=epo).

For this example, *promesi* may be a good match, but I'm not sure what you want to say, could you develop the context?

Answer (score 5):

Pledge to ... = devontigi sin ...i